# How to unlock List Item via Rewarded Video Ads

Tags: android, admob

I want to Unlock a List Items permanently after the user finishes watching a Rewarded Video Ads. How to implement it.
for example:

- List item [unlocked]
- List item [locked]
- List item [locked]   (click on this list item to watch video ads and unlock it)

MainActivity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;     
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
     
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
        "India",
        "Pakistan",
        "Sri Lanka",
        "China",
        "Bangladesh",
        "Nepal",
        "Afghanistan",
        "North Korea",
        "South Korea",
        "Japan"
    };
 
    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
        R.drawable.india,
        R.drawable.pakistan,
        R.drawable.srilanka,
        R.drawable.china,
        R.drawable.bangladesh,
        R.drawable.nepal,
        R.drawable.afghanistan,
        R.drawable.nkorea,
        R.drawable.skorea,
        R.drawable.japan
    };
 
    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
        "Indian Rupee",
        "Pakistani Rupee",
        "Sri Lankan Rupee",
        "Renminbi",
        "Bangladeshi Taka",
        "Nepalese Rupee",
        "Afghani",
        "North Korean Won",
        "South Korean Won",
        "Japanese Yen"
    };
 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
 
        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
 
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
            aList.add(hm);
        }
 
        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };
 
        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};
 
        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
 
        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);
 
        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 
        // Item Click Listener for the listview
        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container, int position, long id) {
                // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
                LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;
 
                // Getting the inner Linear Layout
                LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = (LinearLayout ) linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);
 
                // Getting the Country TextView
                TextView tvCountry = (TextView) linearLayoutChild.getChildAt(0);
 
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tvCountry.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
 
        // Setting the item click listener for the listview
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Layout main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

listview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

OUTPUT is:
[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i8YP.png)
Now when user click on these list item a new activity of that particular country get starts, I want to lock these list item and unlock it permanently when user watch rewarded admob ads. https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video

Comment: Provide more information, what did you do? what were the challenges you faced and how we can help you. What platform are you talking about, what language?

Comment: Done!! Please look into it